# Issue sorting table by Date in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting

I came across this code to sort a table in JQuery and it works fine for sorting strings and numbers, but dates are treated like strings so when sorting `4/4/2015` and `12/12/2015` and `1/1/2015` the result is : `1/1/2015` , `12/12/2015`, `4/42015`. How can I modify this to correctly sort by dates?

```
$('th').click(function () {
    var table = $(this).parents('table').eq(0);
    var rows = table.find('tr:gt(0)').toArray().sort(comparer($(this).index()));
    this.asc = !this.asc;
    if (!this.asc) {
        rows = rows.reverse();
        $(this).find('a').html('&#9662');
    } else {
        $(this).find('a').html('&#9652');
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
        table.append(rows[i]);
    }
});
function comparer(index) {
    return function (a, b) {
        var valA = getCellValue(a, index), valB = getCellValue(b, index);
        return $.isNumeric(valA) && $.isNumeric(valB) ? valA - valB : valA.localeCompare(valB);
    }
}
function getCellValue(row, index) { return $(row).children('td').eq(index).html(); }
```

Comment: `4/4/2015` is a string, not a date.

Comment: You need to convert the string to a date object

Comment: If you format the dates like this:  `YYYY-MM-DD`, they will sort correctly as strings.

Answer (score 1):

I took @epascarello's advice and changed it into a `Date Object` as follows:

```
$('th').click(function () {
    var table = $(this).parents('table').eq(0);

    var rows = table.find('tr:gt(0)').toArray().sort(comparer($(this).index()));
    this.asc = !this.asc;
    if (!this.asc) {
        rows = rows.reverse();
        $(this).find('a').html('&#9662');
    } else {
        $(this).find('a').html('&#9652');
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
        table.append(rows[i]);
    }

});
function comparer(index) {
    return function (a, b) {
        var valA;
        var valB;
        if (getCellValue(a, index).indexOf("/") > -1) //comparing dates
        {
            valA = new Date(getCellValue(a, index)).setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
            valB = new Date(getCellValue(b, index)).setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
        }
        else {
            valA = getCellValue(a, index);
            valB = getCellValue(b, index);
        }
        return $.isNumeric(valA) && $.isNumeric(valB) ? valA - valB : valA.localeCompare(valB);
    }
}
function getCellValue(row, index) { return $(row).children('td').eq(index).html(); }
```